# Word lists for general knowledge crosswords

Tags: crosswords

When using software to create a grid for a cryptic crossword, most general-purpose word lists will do because you want most of the answers to be headwords from a dictionary. But I'd like to compile a general knowledge crossword of the kind that Kate Mepham does for the Telegraph, so the answer mix should be dominated by proper names and certain types of common noun (animals, for example). Are there word lists available for this kind of crossword, or do I need to build the grid by hand?

Comment: https://enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/